# I want to return to initial page after clicking of button

Tags: visualforce

[image]

After Clicking download excel which is linked to a VF page a file is downloaded and a new blank page opens up. I dont want that blank page to open up. What should i do?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Visualforce page, you can simply add

```
return new PageReference('javascript:window.close()');
```

to your Apex controller. This should close the VF page.

Comment: Because of your browser settings, we need your permission to open null... in a new tab. To prevent this message from displaying in the future, disable your browser’s popup blocker

Comment: Not working even though pop up is enabled

Comment: Where in the controller would you add this?